# Zend_Cache_Core showing when I am trying to create cache file in view file

Tags: zend-framework, caching, zend-cache

I am trying to cache a view file content and I am using the following method inside a view file,

```
$frontendOptions = array(
    'lifetime' => 3600,
    'automatic_serialization' => false
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => '../cache'
);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
    'Core',
    'File',
    $frontendOptions,
    $backendOptions
);

$cache->save('somebody', 'fileName', array('tag1', tag2));
```

it is not creating cache file and it is showing the error, the same is working fine in controller.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$cache->save('somebody', 'fileName', array('tag1', tag2));
```

by

```
$cache->save('somebody', 'fileName', array('tag1', 'tag2'));
```

and

```
'cache_dir' => '../cache'
```

by

```
'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../caches'
```

with the `cache` directory at the same level as the `application` directory

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have any problem with cache_dir, it is fine. I have created the cache object in index.php and I am using the same object to create the cache file with content, it is working in controller and not working in view file of that controller. I want to know why it is not working in view file.

Comment: I'm sorry, this fix works for me.
I just thought it'd directory because the view and controller are not on the same level. :)

Answer (score 0):

[K. V. Suresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393669/k-v-suresh) you have to send the the Cache Object created by $cache->load(key) to your view's controller in order to access it there.
From your controller:

```
$data = $cache->load('somebody');
$this->view->cached_data = $data;
```

From view:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->cache_data);
```